# Slicing a dictionary to print specific information

Tags: python-3.x

This is part of something larger i'm working on but i  needed to figure out how to do it for this section in order to move on.

Note: This is not homework, only a personal project.

```
Roxanne = {'Location': 'Rustboro City', 'Type': 'Rock',
       'Pokemon Used': 'Geodude: Lvl 12, Geodude: Lvl 12, Nosepass: Lvl 15'}

user = input("What would you like to learn about: Gym Leaders, Current Team, Natures, or Evolution ")

if user == 'Gym Leaders' or 'gym leaders':

   response = input('Who would you like to learn about? '
                 'Roxanne, Brawly, Wattson, Flannery, Norman, Winona, The Twins, or Juan? ')

      if response == 'Roxanne' or 'roxanne':

        ask = input('What would you like to know about? Location, Type, Pokemon Used ')

          if ask == 'Location' or 'location':

           # i need to print the location part of the Roxanne dictionary here, i.e. 'Rustboro City'
```

I'm just testing to see if I should just print the entire 'Roxanne' dictionary based on user input, or if I should print individual info from it, so that a user can find specific information.

Finally, the only python experience I have is the introductory course I'm taking in Uni right now, so nothing too difficult or complicated. The challenge I set myself was to stay within the boundaries of the course.

Comment: "if user == 'Gym Leaders' or 'gym leaders'" will always be true, because 'gym leaders' is a truthy value.

Comment: `user == 'Gym Leaders' or 'gym leaders'` this will be True everytime, you shoul put `user.lower() == 'gym leaders'`, same for `ask` and `response`

Comment: so if i use user.lower() == 'gym leaders' will it only proceed forward if the lowercase is typed? Because i wanted it so that both version are accepted

Comment: `str.lower` returns a copy of the string converted to lowercase. Using it like this allows input of upper, lower or mixed case and you can handle each with a single check. It's best to test these out and play around with it.

Comment: I'll give that a go for sure. However I do still need to figure out the dictionary slicing